# Apply time formatting to string field in model MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model, time-format

I have a string field TimeAdd in database that I calculate using next extension:

```
    public static string ToIso8601Date(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        DateTimeOffset dateOffset = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(dateTime));
        return dateOffset.ToString("o");
    }
    // here is its result: 2013-04-01T16:16:17.7646200+03:00
```

Here is my model field:

```
    [Column("TimeAdd")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH\:mm}")]
    public string TimeAdd { get; set; }
```

and View() part:

```
     <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeAdd)
     </td>
```

I am not achive my goals.How must I correct use DataFormatString? In my output nothing was changed.

EDIT

Ok.I dont want waste my time so I did next:

```
    public string TimeAdd
    {

        get
        {
            return _timeAdd.Substring(0, 16).Replace("-", " ").Replace("T", "  ") ;
        }

        set
        {
           _timeAdd = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try '@"{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}"' ?

Answer (score 0):

First of, your DataFormatString, expects a DateTime, but you are passing a string. What I would suggest, is that you change your type to DateTime, it is essentially a datetime, then your format string, should work.